# Disable Swap File Generation in Cygwin

Tags: vim, cygwin

I'm getting pretty annoyed of vim automatically generating swap files when I press control-z. Is there any way to disable this feature (and not just delete them)?

Comment: `:help swap<C-d>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your .vimrc:

```
set noswapfile
```

Edit: You could also consider moving backup files to a location where they won't get in your way. I have this in my .vimrc:

```
set noswapfile
" Alternatively, store your swap files in your local .vim folder
" call system('mkdir ~/.vim/swap')
" set dir=~/.vim/swap/

if has('persistent_undo')
  set undolevels=5000
  call system('mkdir ~/.vim/undo')
  set undodir=~/.vim/undo
  set undofile
endif

call system('mkdir ~/.vim/backups')
set backupdir=~/.vim/backups/

" The 'n' here is a prefix specifying which viminfo property is being set -
" in this case, the Name of the viminfo file.
" :h 'viminfo'
set viminfo+=n~/.vim/viminfo
```

I really like the persistent undo, meaning even after quitting vim, restarting the computer etc., you can just undo/redo changes from previous sessions.

Note that if you are using both console vim under Cygwin *and* windows gvim, you'll need to wrap all of this in an `if v:progname != "gvim.exe"` block, since windows won't understand paths like `~/.vim`. I have this section duplicated in my _gvim file using windows paths, for the odd occasion where I use gvim.

Comment: I have that but it's not working. Any idea if it's a Cygwin thing? I have the following in my vimrc: set nobackup, set nowritebackup, set noswapfile, set noundofile

Comment: Are you sure your .vimrc is being read?  Try adding a debugging line like this `echom 'read from .vimrc'` and see if that gets displayed when you load vim.  You can also see echom messages after load by calling `:messages`

Comment: It's not a cygwin thing, I have this working on cygwin

Comment: So I started with a fresh vimrc and realized that set noswapfile now works. But I had to get rid of the following `autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview` and `autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview`

Comment: Any idea why? I liked having those because they saved my code foldings. Any way to have both?

Comment: Ah right, so your .vimrc _was_ setting `noswapfile`, but a previous view was then being loaded and overwriting the setting?

Comment: Reading the help, it looks like you can limit `mkview` to only save folds and cursor position like this `set viewoptions=folds,cursor`. Now options won't be overwritten.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks so much! My other hack was to use vim -n with a bash alias haha